# Is it normal for Hobbits to live without their parents?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Based on [my previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/239107/105264), tried to understand why was Frodo living with Bilbo based on the assumption that it's not something normal. As Nathaniel pointed in a comment,

> It could be perfectly normal for hobbits, as far as we know

So, this assumption was likely being drawn from my human experience. To clarify in case of any doubts, is that normal for hobbits or not?

By normal I mean that the majority would live that way. For instance, it could be considered normal in my hometown to have kids before marriage since 7 out of 10 newborns match that requirement (i know it's possible to judge "normality" based on other criterias (not necessarily through the majority) but that's not the intent here).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, it is not normal.

Tolkien describes Hobbit society in the section 1 of the Prologue. He explicitly singles out Frodo and Bilbo as being unusual in this:

> The houses and the holes of Shire-hobbits were often large, and inhabited by large families. (Bilbo and Frodo Baggins were as bachelors very exceptional, as they were also in many other ways, such as their friendship with the Elves.) Sometimes, as in the case of the Tooks of Great Smials, or the Brandybucks of Brandy Hall, many generations of relatives lived in (comparative) peace together in one ancestral and many-tunnelled mansion. All Hobbits were, in any case, clannish and reckoned up their relationships with great care.

Comment: IIRC, Frodo was also left an orphan after his parents died in a boating accident, as well.

Comment: The fate of Frodo's parents was the topic of the previous question referenced here.

Comment: You say “no”, but then all of your supporting evidence suggests that it is completely normal. The abnormal thing is that there aren’t _more_ family living with them.

Comment: @RubberDuck I think you’ve been confused by the double negative. This answer correctly says that it’s not normal for hobbits to live without their parents, or in other words that it _is_ normal for hobbits to live with their parents.

Comment: It should be noted that Frodo wasn't exactly a kid.  I know Elijah Wood looked young in the movies, but canonically, Frodo was 50 years old at the beginning of LotR.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman But hobbits age more slowly — they’re not considered adults until they’re 33. 50 for a hobbit is about the same as 30 for a human.

Comment: Plus, Frodo had possessed the Ring (and therefore effectively stopped ageing) since he was 33, which maps to about 21.